# Is there a way to fetch my api firsts and updating my empty array state before rendering state

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I'm working on creating this image slider, After making an Api request I'm setting my Persons state to the return value of my API call. but this those not happen immediately my component renders. it logs an [] and after some secs  [{...}] I need it to happen before my initial state renders

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react"

export default function App() {
  const [initValue, setInitValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [persons, setPersons] = React.useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false);

  async function getImages() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await      fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list");
    const resData = await response.json();
    setPersons(resData);
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  React.useEffect(()=> {
    getImages();
  }, [])

const prevClick = () => {
  if(initValue <= 0 ){
    setInitValue(persons.length - 1)
  }else{
    setInitValue(initValue - 1)
  }
} 

const nextClick = () => {
  if(initValue >= persons.length - 1 ){
    setInitValue(0)
  }else{
    setInitValue(initValue + 1)
  }
} 
  return (
    <>
    {isLoading ? (<div>Loading...</div>) : (<div>
     <img src={persons[initValue].download_url} alt="img" style={{width: "100%", height: "300px", objectFit: "cover"}}/>
   </div>)}
  
   <button onClick={prevClick}>prev</button>
   <button onClick={nextClick}>Next</button>
   </>
   )
}
```

Comment: That's how React and async things work. You may wanna provide the default value as true for `isLoading` state, so that it shows the loading text while your data is being fetched.

Comment: Providing a loading state while waiting for a response is better than lets the user wait on an empty page before rendering the first contet.

Comment: Thanks, A lot Bro this worked great for me